# How to make java class for one tabe in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql

Example:i have a database name base1,with one table(product) and data inside her:productid,name,price.
How to create  a class for that table product?
Tnx in advance.

```
public class Product {
private int id;
private String name;
private double price;


public Product(String name) {
 this.name = name;
 this.id = id;
}

private String getName() {
  return name;
}

private String getId() {
  return id;
}

private double getPrice() {
 return price;
 }
```

i  know how to create connection with database,and how to implements methods like insert,delete...but i'm having problem with creating a class.

or...something like this?

```
public class Proizvod {
private int id;
private String naziv;
private String sifra;

public Proizvod() {
}
public Proizvod(int id, String naziv, String sifra) {
    this.id = id;
    this.naziv = naziv;
    this.sifra = sifra;
}
private int getId() {
    return id;
}
private void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
private String getNaziv() {
    return naziv;
}
private void setNaziv(String naziv) {
    this.naziv = naziv;
}
private String getSifra() {
    return sifra;
}
private void setSifra(String sifra) {
    this.sifra = sifra;
}
public void prikaziPodatke() {
    System.out.println("Proizvod:" + naziv+""+id+""+sifra);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As npinti suggested, I strongly second take a look at Hibernate. With the Hibernate Tools, it generates all of the classes automatically. The first steps to make it running a little bit hard though. Hibernate Tools is a plugin can be installed into Eclipse, or Netbeans comes with it (it or a similar tool but does the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to look at [JPA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/jpa-137156.html) (Java Persistance API) or ORM tools such as [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/).